# Have a popup window when a cell is clicked in a grid HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am have trouble figuring out this problem. I need a popup to display when a cell in a 5x8 grid is clicked. I need to enter the information of the user to a database from the popup. I don't need a direct answer but is there a way to approach this? I am very new to this. I could use any technology to accomplish this.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You haven't accepted my answer, yet you haven't left any comments. Does my answer answer your question or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to add an event listener to all table cells like so:

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
cells.forEach((e)=>{
  e.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    alert("cell clicked!");
  })
})
```

```css
td{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also check out [`Window.prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)

Comment: This worked thank you, what should I use to create multiple entries for the dialogue box? window.prompt only takes in a single field. @j1mbl3s

Comment: You'll need something other than `prompt()` for multiple fields, for example you can use the Bootstrap modal as suggested in another answer to display a modal "popup" in the page with a form. Or just call it as many times as you need for entering values.